# PhoneGap 1.1.0 and iOS 5.0 FileWriter does not respond

Tags: cordova

I am using PhoneGap 1.1.0 and iOS 5.0, and have struggled on FileWriter problem.

Here's the full example of http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.1.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileWriter
does work fine.
Creating a FileWriter from the onDeviceReady works.

However, since what I want to do is to create a FileWriter depending on
various filenames on demand, I did as follows:

```
(function ($){
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function ()
{
  var FSroot;
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onInitFs, errorHandler);

  function onInitFs(fs)
  {
       FSroot = fs.root;
       //.......
  }

  //.......

  function writeFile(myText1)
   {
      var filename = "namedProgramatically";

      alert("CHECK1");
      FSroot.getFile(filename, {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail);

      function gotFileEntry(fileEntry)
                         {
                            alert("CHECK2");
                            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
                         }

      function gotFileWriter(writer)
                         {
                            writer.onwrite = function(evt)
                                                  {alert("WRITE Done!!");};
                            writer.write(myText1);
                         }

      function fail(error)
                         {
                              alert(error.code);
                         }


   }
   //...........

 }); //========================
})(jQuery)
```

This code does not work.
I see "CHECK1" alert, but not "CHECK2".
I have no clue, what is wrong?
Please give me some advice.
Thank you.

Ken

(edit)
The problem may be a JavaScript-JQuery scope issue although I'm not sure.
I have re-developed a FileWrite unit test code on iOS5.0+ PhoneGap1.1.0 + JQuery1.7, and finally it works as I intended.
Here is the full working code.(my Google Docs link)

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1B58qVbIldDQ6s_WbPiCwB9MDnXxqlidUBbwQxNP2geg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be a JavaScript-JQuery scope issue although I'm not sure. I have re-developed a FileWrite unit test code on iOS5.0+ PhoneGap1.1.0 + JQuery1.7, and finally it works as I intended. Here is the full working code.(my Google Docs link)

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1B58qVbIldDQ6s_WbPiCwB9MDnXxqlidUBbwQxNP2geg